# Re-rendering map component on the Onchange event lightning: select

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightningselect

I have a lightning select on my component with two values - Leads and Accounts. When the option leads is selected ,I need to  display all the Leads on map and if Accounts is selected then need to display Accounts on map. The issue is I am able to display leads on map when I select the leads option but when I choose Accounts, the component doesn't refreshes and display accounts. Here's the part of my code which does this job-

Component-

-->

```
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account[]" />
<aura:attribute name="lead" type="Lead[]" />
<div class="slds-align_absolute-right ">
      <lightning:select name="Select" label="Select the object" aura:id="Select" onchange="{!c.onChangeObject}"  >
          <option>--Select--</option>
          <option>Accounts</option>
          <option>Leads</option>
      </lightning:select>
  </div>

<aura:attribute name="mapOptions" type="Object" default='{"zoom": 2}' />
<aura:attribute name="mapOptionsCenter" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="mapData" type="Object[]" />


<aura:if isTrue="{!v.acc.length > 0}">
    <c:GoogleMap mapOptions="{!v.mapOptions}" mapOptionsCenter="{!v.mapOptionsCenter}" mapData="{!v.mapData}" />
</aura:if>
```

**JS Controller-**

```
onChangeObject : function(component,event,helper){

       helper.fetchrecords(component, event);

           }
```

**JS Helper-**

```
({
fetchrecords: function(component, event) {
    var selectedValue=component.find("Select").get("v.value");
    console.log('Selected value'+selectedValue);
    if (selectedValue =='Leads'){
        var action = component.get('c.getLeads');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                var leadrec = response.getReturnValue();

                if(leadrec.length > 0){
                    console.log('Lead'+ leadrec[0].Id);

                    var mapOptionsCenter = {"lat":parseFloat(leadrec[0].Latitude), "lng":parseFloat(leadrec[0].Longitude)};
                    var mapData = Array();
                    //cmp.set("v.opportunities", response.getReturnValue());
                    for(var i=0; i<leadrec.length; i++){
                        mapData.push({"lat":parseFloat(leadrec[i].Latitude), "lng":parseFloat(leadrec[i].Longitude),"name":leadrec[i].Name, "markerText":leadrec[i].Id})
                    }

                    component.set('v.mapOptionsCenter', mapOptionsCenter);
                    component.set('v.mapData', mapData);
                    component.set('v.acc', leadrec);
                }
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
    else{
        var action = component.get('c.getAccounts');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state:', state);
            if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                var acc = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('acc:', acc);


                if(acc.length > 0){
                    console.log('acc'+ acc[0].Id);

                    var mapOptionsCenter = {"lat":parseFloat(acc[0].BillingLatitude), "lng":parseFloat(acc[0].BillingLongitude)};
                    var mapData = Array();
                    //cmp.set("v.opportunities", response.getReturnValue());
                    for(var i=0; i<acc.length; i++){
                        mapData.push({"lat":parseFloat(acc[i].BillingLatitude), "lng":parseFloat(acc[i].BillingLongitude),"name":acc[i].Name, "markerText":acc[i].Id})
                    }

                    component.set('v.mapOptionsCenter', mapOptionsCenter);
                    component.set('v.mapData', mapData);
                    component.set('v.acc', acc);
                }
            }

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }

}
```

})

Essentially I am not able to re-render the map. Any idea how can we achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you mentioned is written in salesforce docs as:

[image]

You are not binding the selected value to an attribute, thus you won't get it when you use
`component.find("Select").get("v.value");`

Solution: Bind it to an attribute

```
<aura:attribute type="selectedValue" type="String"/>

<div class="slds-align_absolute-right ">
          <lightning:select name="Select" label="Select the object" aura:id="Select" onchange="{!c.onChangeObject}" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
              <option>--Select--</option>
              <option>Accounts</option>
              <option>Leads</option>
          </lightning:select>
</div>
```

JS controller:

```
onChangeObject : function(component,event,helper){
    var selectedValue=component.get("v.selectedValue");
    console.log(selectedValue);
    helper.fetchrecords(component, event);

}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification

### **Edit:**

As per discussion, the problem is the Map component is not reacting to updated value, so why not have 2 instances of googleMaps components that would be dynamically rendered when selected picklist value is lead or Account

```
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account[]" />
<aura:attribute name="lead" type="Lead[]" />
<aura:attribute type="selectedValue" type="String"/>

<div class="slds-align_absolute-right ">
      <lightning:select name="Select" label="Select the object" aura:id="Select" onchange="{!c.onChangeObject}"  >
          <option>--Select--</option>
          <option>Accounts</option>
          <option>Leads</option>
      </lightning:select>
  </div>

<aura:attribute name="mapOptions" type="Object" default='{"zoom": 2}' />
<aura:attribute name="mapOptionsCenter" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="mapData" type="Object[]" />


<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedValue =='Leads'}">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.acc.length > 0}">
        <c:GoogleMap mapOptions="{!v.mapOptions}" mapOptionsCenter="{!v.mapOptionsCenter}" mapData="{!v.mapData}" />
    </aura:if>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.selectedValue == 'Accounts'}">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.acc.length > 0}">
        <c:GoogleMap mapOptions="{!v.mapOptions}" mapOptionsCenter="{!v.mapOptionsCenter}" mapData="{!v.mapData}" />
    </aura:if>
</aura:if>
```

From SF docs:

> If the value of the isTrue expression changes and evaluates to false,
>   all the components inside the  tag are destroyed. The
>   components are created again if the isTrue expression changes again
>   and evaluates to true.

So when you select Leads the Account varient of googleMaps would be destroyed and lead's version would be created, which would solve your use case.

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_conditional_markup.htm?search_text=aura:if

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87798/discussion-on-answer-by-pranay-jaiswal-re-rendering-map-component-on-the-onchang).